# Is it possible to subtract one layer from another in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency

Is there a way to take two layers of the same size and make the bottom layer transparent everywhere where the top layer isn't transparent? Basically, I want to cut a hole into the bottom layer that has the same shape as the top one. The layers are pixel-based if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why not use a mask?

Comment: I feel that I must have misunderstood this. If you have 2 shapes that are exactly the same and you use one of them to cut the other one, wouldn't you be left with an empty document?

Comment: @Joonas I think they are the same external size but not the same shape.

Comment: Right. That makes sense.

Comment: Does [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77630/52050) answer your question?

Comment: @Cai +1 one your answer. It should be mentioned though that this is great when using text layers and feel that you will edit it in the future but I wouldn't use it for everything since it would leave me with a bunch of layers that I need to keep for the cut. Also having to place it in a group to end it is a downside for me.

Comment: @Alin yeh of course, a mask is easier in a lot of cases. Depends what you have and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop: Cut text from underlying image to expose transparent background](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77626/photoshop-cut-text-from-underlying-image-to-expose-transparent-background)

Answer (score 10):

You can easily achieve this by using a mask on the second layer that is the same shape as the first layer like so:

- Ctrl + Click on the first layer to select it's contents
- Click on the second layer then click the bottom **Add layer mask** button
- Click on the mask and hit Ctrl+i

The way these masks work is that it hides the parts of the layer that you don't want without damaging the layer.

**Black** = *hidden*

**White** = *visible*

*PS: Ctrl+click on the mask shows only the contents of the mask (like I did in the example below when you can only see the light bulb in b&w). Ctrl+click again to come back to normal.*

*PS: PS: You can disable the mask without deleting it by Shift+clicking on it. Do the same to enable it again*

[image]

> Joonas's note in the comments:

*Incase someone who is working with Shape layers finds this, it should be mentioned that this isn't the way you'd actually want to do it. If you have Shape layers, merge both layers and use Path operations or a Vector mask.*

Comment: Incase someone who is working with Shape layers finds this, it should be mentioned that this isn't the way you'd actually want to do it. If you have Shape layers, merge both layers and use Path operations or a Vector mask.

Comment: @Joonas Well yeah :)) I just found it faster to create the example.

Comment: @Joonas Added it as a note in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is really close to what I want. Right now it's just cutting the lower layer to the size of the content of the upper layer, making anything outside the mask invisible. I'm looking for the inverted version, making everything inside the mask invisible but keeping the outside.

Comment: @Guest65i7 You just invert the mask, Ctrl+i inverts the mask. And making it the same size, press Ctrl+T (transform) on your first layer, check out the W (width) and H (height), note those down and then press Ctrl+T On the second layer and type the values of the first layer to make it the exact size.

Comment: If more answers could be animated gifs the world would be complete.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I try to do that as much as possible. It's easier for people to understand if the one asking the question doesn't even know the terms.